# Which classification to choose?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, sentiment-analysis, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I have huge amount of  yelp data and I have to classify the reviews into 8 different categories. 
Categories

```
Cleanliness
Customer Service
Parking
Billing
Food Pricing
Food Quality
Waiting time
Unspecified
```

Reviews contains multiple categories so I have used multilable classification. But I am confuse how I can handle the positive/negative . Example review may be for positive for food quality but negative for customer service. Ex- `food taste was very good but staff behaviour was very bad. so review contains positive food quality but negative Customer service` How can I handle this case? Should I do sentiment analysis before classification? Please help me

Comment: This type of problem is called Aspect Based Sentiment Analysis. You can google for papers with that name. Also, check out SemEval task for Aspect Based Sentiment Analysis.

Comment: You can make custom labels like (good food review, bad food review, good customer service, bad customer service etc). Maybe this can help :- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multioutput-classification

Comment: Wrong place to ask, rather go to https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is your dataset supervised ? Are your labels continuous values (stars between 0-5) ?

Comment: @Cedias converted the reviews into sentences and label each sentence based on categories and add positive/negative.

Comment: @lucy you could manually label the sentences like you did, but after that train another model only for sentiment analysis on the sentences. Then you could classify a review into "good in general" (positive - unspecified) but "too expensive" ("negative - food pricing)

Comment: @lucy [here](https://github.com/thestrox/Aspect-Based-Sentiment-Analysis) is the very basic approach for doing this sort of problems. Please be warned that I have yet to refactor the code. 
Firstly, I have predicted aspect category using multi-label classification. Then, I have used multi-label classification for EACH sentiment (pos, neg, neu) to determine the sentiment of predicted aspect category.

Comment: @THe_strOX example- food is good but no parking for car. As you said first predicted aspect categories [Food quality,Parking]. How you do the sentiment ? How you get food quality -> positive and parking -> negative using above example sentence

Comment: I used 1 multi-label classification for 1 sentiment(pos, neg or neu) i.e. total 3. So, for +ve multi-label classification your aspects/categories/labels in training set should have value '1' in Food quality and '0' in other. Similarly, for -ve multi-label classification your aspects/categories/labels in training set should have value '1' in Parking and '0' in other. In this way you should prepare your training set. You can just see from In[31] in the link I provided above.This is the simplest method I could think of.There are other better methods which you can find just by googling for papers.

Answer (score 1):

I think your data is very similar to **Restaurants reviews**. It contains around 100 reviews, with varied number of aspect terms in each ([More information](http://metashare.ilsp.gr:8080/repository/browse/semeval-2014-absa-restaurant-reviews-trial-data/1790ab94464211e388f5842b2b6a04d79bb0323cac4f49939bf5b99878dc38be/)). So you can use **Aspect-Based Sentiment Analysis** like this:

**1-Aspect term Extraction**

Extracting the aspect terms from the reviews.

**2-Aspect Polarity Detection**

For a given set of aspect terms within a sentence, determine whether the polarity of each aspect term is positive, negative.

**3-Identify the aspect categories**

Given a predefined set of aspect categories (e.g., food quality, Customer service), identify the aspect categories discussed in a given sentence.

**4-Determine the polarity**

Given a set of pre-identified aspect categories (e.g., food quality, Customer service), determine the polarity (positive, negative) of each aspect category.

Please see [this](https://www.slideshare.net/IndranilMukherjee20/absa-project-60961283) for more information about similar project.

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would need a sentiment analysis. Why don't you create tokens of your data, that is find the required words out of the sentence, now the most possible approach for you is to find the related words along with their sentiment. i.e. food was good but the cleanliness was not appropriate

In this case you have [ food, good, cleanliness, not, appropriate ] now food links with its next term and cleanliness to its next terms "not appropriate"

again you can classify either into two classes i.e. 1,0 for good and bad .. or you can add classes based upon your case.
Then you would have data as such:

```
--------------------
FEATURE     |  VAL
--------------------
Cleanliness    0
Customer      -1
Service       -1
Parking       -1
Billing       -1
Food Pricing  -1
Food Quality   1
Waiting time  -1
Unspecified   -1
```

I have given this just as an example where -1,1,0 are for no review, good and bad respectively. You can add more categories as 0,1,2 bad fair good
I may not be so good in answering this, but this is what i feel about it.

Note : You need to understand that you model cannot be perfect because that's what Machine Learning is all about, you have to be wrong. Your model cannot give a perfect classification it has to be wrong for certain inputs which it will learn with time and improve over.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways of doing multi label classification.

The simplest one would be having a model for each class, and if the review achieves a certain threshold score for that label, you would apply that label to the review.

This would treat the classes independently, but it seems like a good solution to your problem.